# 'PERCENT_RANK' is not a recognized built-in function name in Business Objects 4.2

Tags: sql-server, business-objects, business-objects-sdk

I use BO 4.2 + SQL Server 2008 for reporting. Design mode for report allows using of data ranking in a query filters including percent ranking. For percent ranking BO calls `PERCENT_RANK()` function in SQL Server. It appears the error message

> 'PERCENT_RANK' is not a recognized built-in function name
>
> [image]

I know this function was introduced in SQL Server 2012. My questions are

- why BO Designer allows add percent rank to query and this button is not disabled/hidden working with SQL Server 2008?
- what ways to disable/hide this button?

p.s. You can find this button by way: -> Design of report -> Edit Data Provider -> Query Filter panel -> Add a database ranking -> set '% top' (See screen)

p.p.s Using BO 3.1 this button is disabled in my case and it is OK, but I need fix it for BO 4.2.

Thank you

Comment: Maybe because the programmers didn't think anyone would still be using software that out of date and didn't want to spend the time to program around that. Developers typically don't go backwards compatible that far back. however, asking the general world why some specific programmers is a pointless exercise. The software works theway it does and we can't change that nor can you.

Comment: I'm voting to close  and delete this question as off-topic because it is not answerable and is a pointless question.

Comment: I don't think so and don't agree with you, as I know SAP still is supporting of SQL Server 2008 now. Let me find an official information. In any case I would like to know another opinions and answers. Thanks.

Comment: Just because some programs support it doesn't mean they will fully support it or that they will make special changes to identify new functionality that version doesn't have. Those things are expensive to do for little gain.  Some companies don't worry so much about backward programmability. Anyway if you are working with SQL server 2008, you should have know that it did not have that function without being told by the software.

Comment: @HLGEM However as I know `BusinessObjects` supports sql sever 2008. So if you buy this product you will expect it, isn't it? BO is not a cheap product. As for me this situation looks strange. I don't understand why do you try to close the question and decrease reputation of the topic starter...

Comment: Because the question does not fit this forum. We cannot know why their programmers made the choices they did. This question is unanswerable and is basically a rant against some software. What did you hope to gain from this question? There is no technical problem to solve.

Comment: @HLGEM if you do not know an answer - np. Let's give a chance for community. Community can know some configuration flags to enable supporting and so on.

Answer (score 0):

SAP support:

> 1)Tested the scenario in-house on 4.2 SP3 Patch3 by doing the
>   following steps
>
> -Created a report based on SQL SERVER 2008 R2 Universe.
>
> -Take some objects in result pane .
>
> -Now in the Query Filter Pane ,click on database tracking ->select % Top option ->Select objects.
>
> -run the report.
>
> -Error thrown is exactly the same which you are getting "The following database error occurred: [Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0] :
>   'PERCENT_RANK' is not a recognized built-in function name. For
>   information about this error, please refer to SAP Knowledge Base
>   Article 2054721 on the SAP Support Portal. (IES 10901) (Error: INF )”
>   "
>
> 2)Now tested the same above scenario by creating a report on SQL
>   SERVER 2012  Universe and it worked fine.
>
> 3)The reason being is the SQL SERVER 2008 R2 is not able to recognize
>   the percent_rank function as the this functionality was introduced by
>   Microsoft on SQL SERVER 2012.
>
> Information about this is provided in the below link
>
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/percent-rank-transact-sql
>
> 4)Also now coming to disabling the option. Now if you don't want to
>   see the %TOP option use Applet mode or Rich Client instead of HTML
>   mode .
>
> As this option is by default in HTML mode .

:D